# Import gi module Bash n Windows 10

Tags: bash, windows, python3, anaconda

How can I import module gi in Python 3.6.5 from Anaconda, with Bash on Windows 10? I have tried following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526026/how-to-install-gi-module-for-anaconda-python3

changing the beginning of the path to

```
> /mnt/c/Users/SOMEBODY/Anaconda3
```

I have found Anaconda3 and its files and folders, but I cannot proceed with the last soft link from the answer. (I didn't have to create the first soft link, because the system was announcing that the location already exists.) It couldn't find files/directory further than

```
> /mnt/c/Users/SOMEBODY/Anaconda3
```

although I have tried

```
> /mnt/c/Users/SOMEBODY/Anaconda3/envs
```

- envs is listed in Anaconda 3.

Here is the messy abstract of /Anaconda3:

```
> SOMEBODY@LAPTOP-8IDQPNIQ:~$ ls /mnt/c/Users/SOMEBODY/Anaconda3/ 
DLLs
> LICENSE_PYTHON.txt 
Lib 
Library 
Menu 
Scripts 
Tools

> api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
> api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
> api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
> api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
> concrt140.dll 
conda-meta 
condabin 
cwp.py
```

> envs

```
etc 
include
libs 
man
> msvcp140.dll 
msvcp140_1.dll 
python.exe 
python.pdb
> python3.dll 
python37.dll 
python37.pdb 
pythonw.exe 
pythonw.pdb 
qt.conf
```

I have already installed PyGObject using `conda` command.

Comment: You might be not able to create sym(bolic) links aka soft links on a Windows drive (`/mnt/c`) but you could use the [Linux drive in WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#are-files-in-the-linux-drive-different-from-the-mounted-windows-drive). @j-money This is not really a Windows question. Ubuntu running using WSL is supported even here on AU.

Comment: My mistake! Apologies

Comment: _“I cannot proceed the last soft link from the answer.”_ Did you succeed with the _first_ soft link? Please [edit] your question to include the complete command you issued and its output.

Comment: Sorry, I had some hardships. I didn't have to create the first soft link, because the system was anouncing that the location already exists.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, as I immersed in your problem, I found that you are trying to solve a problem inside Windows using instructions for Linux which might not work. I find especially creating the Linux symlinks to be used on Windows an unreliable way. You should get instructions on how to do it in Windows. If the answers to the linked question don’t help you, start a new question on [so], include the link to the original one but specify you are trying it on Windows.